# Word for swinging a weapon upward?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would represent the motion of swinging a melee weapon (Bat, Sword, hammer, axe, etc) starting at your legs and moving upward.

The end of the weapon would be starting on or close to the ground, then it would be making an uppercut motion.

Examples that don't quite fit:

- Bash - Thrusting a blunt object forward
- Slash - Diagonal upward or downward attack
- Stab - Thrusting a sharp object forward
- Sweep - Swinging from one-side to another
- Crush - Downward swing of a weapon (exact opposite of what I'm currently looking for)

Comment: Did you you look at any fencing or swordsmanship references? They probably have technical vocab for just this. Tierce? Prima?

Comment: I have now, the problem with the fencing, sword, and katana terms is that I'm finding they're either too specific adding in extra details or just use "upward cut". I was hoping to find a single word to describe this action in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, for all weapons (axe, sword):

> **upswing:** *(v.)* an upward swing or movement

Sword:

> **unterhau** *(v.)* Medieval fencing term for upward or rising strikes made from below the waist

[[YouTube]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vE55CW9VVrU)

Bat:

> **uppercut:** *(v.)* hit with an upward batting stroke

Answer (score 0):

'Brandish or flourish'or even'uphold' may be used.

Comment: Hi Barid Baran Acharya. This is a great answer, but it would benefit from having cited definitions of the words added to it.